# Why isn’t “this” a pronoun?

Tags: grammar

I don’t have access to *CGEL*, but I am reading [Huddleston & Pullum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521612888) (Yes, the 2005 ed.). They categorize *this* in “This is infuriating” as a fused determiner-head. I think I understand their reasoning and I accept it. But on the very next page (p. 99) they categorize *what* in “What do you want?” as a pronoun functioning as a head. I think I understand that too. But I don’t understand why they treat *this* and *what* differently in the respective sentences.

My understanding of their view on *this* is that there’s a fusion that could be split up into *this thing* or something like it. But the same splitting could be done to their *what* example: *What thing do you want?*

So I checked their test(s) for pronounhood, but unfortunately all they address is distinguishing pronouns from other nouns.

In their discussion of *what* they mention that as a pronoun it’s non-personal and as a determinative it’s “neutral with respect to the personal vs non-personal distinction.” I’d say that here too *this* acts the same: **This just invited me to dinner* doesn’t work, but *This professor explains things clearly* does.

So, am I missing something? Besides the determiner *this*, what’s wrong with saying there’s also a **pronoun** *this*? In their *this* example they describe it as belonging to the flavor of fused determiner-head that they label as “special,” but I don’t see anywhere where they explain that label. Could that be a clue?

(Of course, the same thing would go for *that*.)

Comment: I agree that their explanation is inadequate, particularly as "what" can in fact be a fused determiner-head in, for example, "I don't like _what she wrote_", where "what" is simultaneously determiner and head.

Comment: @BillJ It gets mind-bogglingly confusing, but the *what* in *I didn't like what she wrote* is not a fused determiner-head, it's a fused head-prenucleus.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, it's important to distinguish fused relatives and fused determiner-head NPs. But I still think H&P's explanation in SIEG is inadequate.

Comment: @BillJ I agree. It's not wrong, but it needs unpacking a whole lot to be a) convincing and b) coherent. Have they change it for the 2nd ed?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I haven't got a copy of SIEG2 But I'm aware of a few inconsistencies with SIEG1 / CGEL, which I've discussed at length with GKP. He agrees, and says he'll get them corrected in the first reprint. It's apparent from the little I've heard/read that RDH has made little input in SIEG2, but then you and I know why.

Comment: @BillJ (1) Wait, you *know* GKP? (2) Why has RDH made little input? I need this mysterious gossip.

Answer (score 3):

> In their discussion of *what* they mention that as a pronoun it’s non-personal and as a determinative it’s “neutral with respect to the personal vs non-personal distinction.” I’d say that here too *this* acts the same

No it does not. Compare:

1. This guy appears to be in charge.
2. This appears to be the guy in charge.
3. What guy appears to be in charge?
4. * What appears to be the guy in charge?

(1) and (2) are both correct. *This* is usually non-personal when used without a following noun, since we would typically use *he, she,* or *they* instead. But it can be used to refer to a person, as (2) shows.

On the other hand, while (3) is correct, (4) is not. When *what* is used on its own, it is *always* non-personal, making (4) incorrect (with the relevant interpretation). So (4) can't be seen as a fused determiner-head, since *what* has a different meaning here than it does as a determiner.

*Edit:* There is a further complication here, as Huddleston & Pullum note on p. 904. *What* can occur as a predicative complement with the ascriptive *be*, as in Araucaria's "If Mitch is the ringleader, what is Alphabet?" example. Here the expected answer is not a referential noun phrase denoting a person, so this does not violate the general rule.

Comment: If Mitch is the ringleader, what is Alphabet? (Devil's advocating for a sec).

Comment: Your examples there aren't really parallel there. For (4) to parallel (1), you'd need "What is the guy buying groceries". Can you come up with some parallel examples?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Your counterexamples have successfully confused me.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. OK, I was able to answer the "ringleader" issue.

Comment: Nice. I can't upvote you though, I'm afraid. I did that already.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I was also able to come up with some parallel examples that I believe work; the new version of (4) uses a raising verb, which avoids the predicative complement interpretation because you can't raise a predicative complement into a subject.

Comment: Hey, @alphabet, doesn’t your argument establish that *this* **can be** different from *what* (i.e., a fused determiner-head)? That proposition I don’t dispute. No, what is unclear to me is that it **cannot  be** a pronoun in constructions like *This is confusing*.Have I merely failed to read your argument closely enough?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Their view is that there is no *reason* why it would be necessary to posit that *this* is a pronoun in any such sentences, so, for the sake of simplicity and consistency, it can be treated exclusively as a fused determiner-head. You can, of course, disagree with their view that fused determiner-heads exist, but that's the analysis that they use.